# How to associate Window Procedure to my existing dialog window

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, windows-messages

I had a Windows dialog-based project, which is auto-generated by VS 2013. Now I want to add code to detect usb device insert. I read code sample [refer 1](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devio/detecting-media-insertion-or-removal). It's a Window Procedure can handle message. I also know I had to associate this WinProc to a WNDCLASS object and call RegisterClass, like sample code [refer 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-window-procedures).

However, my code generated by VS 2013 seems not the case. For example, I can't find a WinMain like ***refer 2***. It begins from a global CWinApp::MyApp object and in the MyApp::InitInstance() creates and opens my main dialog window. I implement details in the dialog implementation.

I don't know how to associate the Window Procedure with my main dialog. Or how can I do in the main dialog when USB inserted the Main_OnDeviceChange( HWND hwnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) in ***refer 1*** will be called automatically.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem using a framework you do not understand. MFC is challenging; you first need to come to terms with that framework. As written, this question is neither answerable nor helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of 2 steps in the main dialog class .

1. Add ***ON_WM_DEVICECHANGE()*** between BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP and END_MESSAGE_MAP
2. Add afx_msg BOOL OnDeviceChange(UINT nEventType, DWORD dwData); and implement it.

The OnDeviceChange is a default name. It fails to function if change the name.

Answer (score -1):

I failed to access the links of the samples but as I understand from your question that the samples are written using Windows APIS while your application is an MFC Dialog based application.

I think you need only to override the WindowProc method in the Dialog Class

```
LRESULT WindowProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{       
    return CWnd::WindowProc(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```